# Unable to get tests to run in firefox (playwright - all actions timeout)

Tags: typescript, playwright

Very strange, I can't seem to get a single test to run in Firefox, it always times out on actions (i.e. setChecked(true), click(), etc). Locators are fine, and if I set focus on elements and instead do keyboard input/presses I can get things to work.

I even tried creating a simple dummy test, navigate to google, enter text and click on search. Click times out.

Again locators are fine, any element and locator type works and can be found on the page. Assertions also work (i.e. element...isVisible). It's actions like click! And without click, well I can't do much.

Example output: See on setChecked, that's the 'error' it just doesn't work.

```
 8 |     await checkBox.isVisible();
    >  9 |     await checkBox.setChecked(true);
         |                    ^
      10 |     await expect(checkBox).toBeChecked();
```

Webkit and Chrome are perfectly fine, no issues. In my project I have like 40 fairly complex/involved tests running flawlessly on those browsers, but firefox simply refuses to work. I've updated playwright, installed the latest browsers, no go.

I have zero idea what is going on, and I can't seem to find anyone else who has encountered the issue.

--- Minimal example not from my project, but I tried a similar simple test going to google and running a search

```
const { test, expect } = require("@playwright/test");
test("simple test", async ({
  page,
}) => {
  await page.goto("https://playwright.dev/"); 
  await expect(page).toHaveTitle(/Playwright/); 
  const getStarted = page.locator("text=Get Started"); 
  await expect(getStarted).toHaveAttribute("href", "/docs/intro");
  await getStarted.click(); // In firefox this will fail/timeout.
  await expect(page).toHaveURL(/.*intro/);
});
```

Comment: Done, thanks btw being new on stack seeing how to do it right is appreciated :)

Comment: Thanks. The test you shared passes though for me, so it's still not reproducible. I ran your exact code with `npx playwright test --browser=firefox` and the test passed. `"@playwright/test": "^1.39.0"`, Node v18.16.1.